# Drawables not recognized when using custom namespace

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I'm using a view from a custom library. How can I get Android Studio to recognize this as a valid option to parse through my drawables directory? I'd like to be able to see my options as I type (the autofill menu that appears)

[image]

This is how I'm setting the variable in my custom view's class:

```
int rightIconId = a.getResourceId(a.getIndex(R.styleable.ToolbarITI_rightIconSrc), -1);
if (rightIconId != -1)
    rightIcon.setImageResource(rightIconId);
```

These are the custom attributes (I have a feeling my format is incorrect)

```
<declare-styleable name="ToolbarITI">
    <attr name="rightIconSrc" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="leftIconSrc" format="integer"/>
    ...
</declare-styleable>
```

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected, my format was incorrect. Changing the format of the attribute to "reference" did the trick.